# How to deploy django channels with Apache and Daphne?

Tags: django, apache, reverse-proxy, channel, daphne

I am trying to deploy this django app which uses channels. I use Apache for regular HTTP requests and want to forward the web socket requests to Daphne.

Here are some of my important files:

**apache config:**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
DocumentRoot /var/www/html
ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP:UPGRADE} ^WebSocket$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:CONNECTION} ^Upgrade$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* ws://127.0.0.1:8001%{REQUEST_URI} [P,QSA,L]

Alias /static /home/anna/tchan/static
<Directory /home/anna/tchan/static>
Require all granted
</Directory>

Alias /media /home/anna/tchan/media
<Directory /home/anna/tchan/media>
Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /home/anna/tchan/tchan>
<Files wsgi.py>
Require all granted
</Files>
</Directory>

WSGIScriptAlias / /home/anna/tchan/tchan/wsgi.py
WSGIDaemonProcess django_app python-path=/home/anna/tchan python-home=/home/anna/tchan/venv
WSGIProcessGroup django_app

</VirtualHost>
```

Last few lines of **settings.py**:

```
ASGI_APPLICATION = 'tchan.routing.application'

CHANNEL_LAYERS = {
'default': {
'BACKEND': 'channels_redis.core.RedisChannelLayer',
'CONFIG': {
"hosts": [('127.0.0.1', 8001)],
},
},
}
```

**asgi.py**

```
import os
import django
from channels.routing import get_default_application

from django.core.asgi import get_asgi_application

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'tchan.settings')
django.setup()
application = get_default_application()
```

With these in place, I run `daphne -p 8001 tchan.asgi:application` and then `sudo service apache2 reload`.
Finally, when testing the websocket in my page here's what happens:

> websocket.js:4 WebSocket connection to 'ws://192.168.0.57/ws/chat/8/' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 403

This error 403 happens whether or not I'm running daphne.

What am I doing wrong here?
Note: the app works as expected when using Django's development server and docker for the channel layer, the problem is with my Apache config, I think.

Comment: I am doing the same thing too but cannot find any good lead from where to deploy it, any tutorials or references you can give to deploy my channels asynchronous website internet

Answer (score 3):

I figured it out. To enable apache to redirect, we need to:

```
sudo a2enmod proxy
sudo a2enmod proxy_http
sudo a2enmod proxy_wstunnel
```

One of these was not enabled which caused the 403 Forbidden.

Answer (score 0):

Apache currently doesn't support to run ASGI server. So you should use ir as a reverse proxy instead of a webserver.

You should be running the daphne as a service in the background and make a proxy in the apahce config for the location /ws/ and proxy them to the external daphne server.

Answer (score 0):

1. Add this string in your `virtualhost`:

   ```
   ProxyPass /ws ws://localhost:8000/path/to/websocket
   ProxyPassReverse /ws ws://localhost:8000/path/to/websocket
   ```
2. Add this string to Apache `http.conf`:

   ```
   LoadModule proxy_wstunnel_module 
   modules/mod_proxy_wstunnel.so
   ```
3. Run `django python.manage.py runserver`
4. JavaScript code:

   ```
   new WebSocket('wss://you.url.com/ws');
   ```

This works in my project.